# How to add another filter to Scald search?

Tags: 7, scald

I have added new field to the Scald Image atom `admin/structure/scald`which is called description and it is text area multiple rows. Now I want to have this field in the search to be shown at the below screen shot.

I tried to edit the field by checking `MEE Enabled` but I could not get it in the search.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search is provided by a View called Scald Atoms.  Add the filters you want to that view.

Comment: Actually you are better off cloning the scald_library view and making your changes to your cloned one, disabling the original view.